# Installing Hashcat with Intel Celeron CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, intel

I am trying to install hashcat on my ubuntu box and am having issues with drivers. I successfully installed hashcat 3.30 but when I run it I am given this error:

```
hashcat (v3.30-49-g2f81532) starting...

* Device #1: Intel's OpenCL runtime (GPU only) is currently broken
             We need to wait for an update of their OpenCL drivers
             You can use --force to override this but do not post error reports if you do so
No devices found/left
```

I haven't been able to find anything in my google searches for my computer. Is there an opencl driver I need to install to fix this. Does hashcat work with Intel Celeron N2840?

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: @Arturo Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while creating a tutorial on how to install hashcat on Ubuntu 18.04; I've included the instructions below for Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors- feel free to review my [full gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/d00a56a51127e73b70a2cdffcd75c9e2).  Hope that helps!

### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option A (Recommended)

1. Check your CPU system processor architecture by running `sudo lscpu` to identify the class of CPU e.g. "Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60Ghz"- alternatively, you can go to Settings > Details which will also reveal the CPU-family (e.g. Intel (R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)).
2. Go to the [Intel Developer Zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#graph-lin-ubuntu) and scroll down to the corresponding download link for your system; assuming you're running Ubuntu 18.04 and have a Intel Core-class CPU, scroll down to "Linux* OS Ubuntu* 16.04.x (deb)" and click on the [Github link for 18.46.11837 Runtimes](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases) to access the runtime-packages to download.
3. There should be instructions within the aforementioned Github repo- or you can proceed with the following in the next steps.
4. `cd ~/Desktop`
5. `mkdir neo`
6. `cd neo`
7. `sudo wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-gmmlib_18.4.0.348_amd64.deb`
8. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-core_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
9. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-opencl_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
10. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-opencl_18.46.11837_amd64.deb`
11. Install the packages by running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
12. Restart the system by running `sudo reboot`.

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option B

1. Go to [Intel OpenCL Runtimes website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) and scroll down to the bottom of the page to Download Intel CPU Runtime for OpenCL Applications 18.1 for LINUX OS (64-bit only).
2. After downloading the OpenCL Runtimes for Intel Processors, `cd ~/Downloads`
3. Run `sudo tar -xzf l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013.tgz` to unpack the tgz file- please note, the OpenCL file version may update since the time as of this gist (ie as of this gist, the version is 18.1.0.013.)
4. `cd l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013`
5. Run `sudo ./install.sh`
6. A welcome screen is prompted- hold-down the "Enter" key until able to input select "2" for "I do NOT consent to the collection of my Information"
7. Hit "1"
8. Hit "1"
9. Hit "Enter" and then restart the computer.
10. If any additional Intel OpenCL errors are encountered after testing hashcat, go to section 'Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - B'- if not, proceed with section "Testing Hashcat"